# automatically login user using session in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I encountered an error where the User automatically logouts after a redirect from an external website (payment portal).

I'm trying to use session to login the user with the use of session but it's not working.

Controller 1 which send POST request to external website

```
 $userid = Auth::User()->id;
    Session::put('userid', $userid);
```

Controller 2 which receives POST request from external website

```
Auth::loginUsingId(Session::get('userid'));
```

The user data is there but the user is forcefully logged out after the redirect.

Log after the redirect

`Authenticate middleware was used: payment. [{"App\\Models\\User":{"id":2,"username":"testuser","accname":"John Smith"}}]`

Comment: why you need that ? if user already login and you redirect to `external website (payment portal)` if redirect to your application you r still login no need to re-login

Comment: the problem is, the user is logged out after the redirect and I don't know why.

Comment: what auth your using?

Comment: ```use Auth;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;```

Comment: what is it ? ... did you create auth system ?

Comment: it's the default ```'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,```

Comment: is your login session valid on in `single browser tab` means if you close browser then user will logout ?

Comment: session is valid with multiple tabs and logouts after 5 minutes of inactivity.  Problem is, the user is logged out if redirected outside the website which is the payment portal

Comment: `5 minutes of inactivity.` this you have implemented via cookies i guess that's why it is not working you need to use session base auth as laravel come with default

Answer (score 0):

Controller 1

```
$userid = Auth::User()->id;
Session::put('userid', $userid);
```

Controller 2

```
$user = User::where("id",Session::get('userid'))->first();
if(isset($user->id)){
  Auth::login($user);
}else{
    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

Comment: Authenticate middleware was used: payment. [{"App\\Models\\User":{"id":2,"username":"testuser","accname":"John Smith"}}]

Comment: user was stored in session but on controller 2, it still becomes null after redirect